# Operator Overloading - C++

Tags: c++

```
class sock  {
public:
    SOCKET m_hSock;
.....
//Other functons...contructors, destructors
.....
    operator SOCKET()
        { return m_hSock;}

}
```

In above coscket class code, what operator it is overloading?

Comment: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/910-overloading-typecasts/

Answer (score 5):

This is known as the type cast operator. Operators of the form;

```
operator Type()
```

where Type is the desired type, are generally known as cast operators and can be used in casting operations, such as `static_cast<Type>(obj)`

Comment: - and it can be used for *implicit cast*

Comment: @ikh Yes. In C++11 the operator can be marked as `explicit` which would then not allow that to happen. This is not to say anything about the implicit or explicit construction of the object being _cast to_.

Comment: @Nipun, off the top of my head, not too many. API compatibility springs to mind first, as in the OP; it could be used when you have a situation when you need to _convert the type to_ another type, without change the type _being converted to_.